# Custom IPrincipal with Forms Authentication in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authorization, iprincipal

This should be simple, but I simply cannot figure it out after all my googling. Here's what I want. I have a custom Users table (no roles at the moment) that I'd like to authorize against. For this I'll have to implement a custom Membership Provider which I've already done. My question is though, how do I go about setting a custom IPrincipal to the HttpContext.Current.User? Where should that happen? Let's say I have the following setup:

```
public class CustomMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
{
   private IUserRepository _repository;

   public CustomMembershipProvider(IUserRepository repository)
   {
      _repository = repository;
   }

   public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
   {
      //check user repository 
   }

   //additional methods omitted for brevity 
}
```

I then have a custom user class the implements `IPrincipal` and `IIdentity`

```
 public class CustomUser : IPrincipal
    {
        public CustomUser(string name, int userId, string additionalInfo)
        {
            Identity = new CustomIdentity(name, userId, additionalInfo);
        }

        public IIdentity Identity { get; private set; }

        public bool IsInRole(string role)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public class CustomIdentity : IIdentity
    {
        public CustomIdentity(string name, int userId, string additionalInfo)
        {
            Name = name;
            UserId = userId;
            AdditionalInfo = additionalInfo;
        }

        public string Name { get; private set; }

        public string AuthenticationType
        {
            get { return "CustomAuth"; }
        }

        public bool IsAuthenticated
        {
            get { return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Name); }
        }

        public int UserId { get; private set; }
        public string AdditionalInfo { get; private set; }
    }
```

So my question is, where is the correct place to set the Context.User to an instance of this custom user? Do I need a custom Authorize Attribute? If so, what would that look like?

Comment: How did you get on with this in the end?  I'm in the early days of doing something similar to this myself.

Comment: I'm on the same boat, i'm almost ready to create an extension method to do the job!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using a custom controller base class for all your controllers

Then, in `OnAuthorization`, call

```
protected override void OnAuthorization(System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    // Actual Authentication
    HttpContext.User = user; 
    Thread.CurrentPrincipal = user;
    base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
}
```

I'm not entirely sure how to invoke the membership provider because I'm doing it manuallt, but I think you have static access to `Membership.Provider` to perform the actual object construction.

> > Do I need a custom Authorize Attribute?

No. Notice the difference of authentication and authorization: authentication establishes the user's identity in your system. Authorization allows or denies a specific request. Hence, `AuthorizeAttribute` also has a `Roles` parameter to allow an action to be called only by certain users.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your answer. When you say Actual Authentication, are you talking about actually setting the AuthCookie there? What then would the Loing form itself do on post?

Comment: The way I understand the MembershipProvider, ValidateUser shouldn't be called very often - as soon as the user logs in, he recvs an authentication cookie which will be used henceforth. However, to get the user object you'll have to hit the database (or some cache). But that's a requirement of your code. I think the MembershipProvider is not very well designed, doing it manually has a lot of benefits.

Comment: Now you changed your comment while I was writing mine :) `OnAuthorization` will be called for every request, even if the user is already (forms-)authenticated; You're hitting the DB only to fetch the user object.

Comment: Sorry about that :) Hitting the DB on every request sounds less than ideal. More than that though, I'm still unclear as to what the //Actual Authentication part should look like. In my Login form I'd call MembershipProvider.Validate() (or something custom as you suggest), but then what should happen for every request in the OnAuthorization?

Comment: `OnAuthorization` merely fetches the user object from the database so you have your user set up. You probably need the user in every request anyway -- for example, to make sure the user is allowed that particular request at this time. Caching is a good idea, of course. Then you can safely access HttpContext.User at all times. The actual authentication (I didn't write that) is what happens when the form is submitted and `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie` is called.